# .htaccess URL rewrite: file.php?param=val --> removing 'file.php?param='

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Just solved one problem proofreading my post, great! :P

Currently I have this code:

```
# To externally redirect /file.php?page=cat/subcat/page to /cat/subcat/page
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} file.php?page=(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /cat/subcat/page to /file.php?page=cat/subcat/page
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ file.php?page=$1 [L]
```

First of all, I hope it's syntactically correct/efficient... I suck at regex!

---

Right now, visiting:

/cat/subcat/page

works correctly

---

However if I visit

/file.php?page=cat/subcat/page

the page does not redirect to cat/subcat/page.

---

Internal/external refirection, regex, and .htaccess a whole confuses me, so I'm not sure where I should be looking for the problem. If it means anything, both the htaccess and file.php file are located at www.website.com/test/, not the website root.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your regex is wrong in first rule.

Try these rules:

```
  RewriteEngine On

  # To externally redirect /file.php?page=cat/subcat/page to /cat/subcat/page
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /file\.php\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

  # To internally forward /cat/subcat/page to /file.php?page=cat/subcat/page
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ file.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfectly, just had to add a ? after /%1 or else the query string was added onto the end, e.g.

/querystring?page=querystring

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.